# How to emulate <nested:root> from Struts 1 in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-1

I am working on converting a Struts 1 app to Struts 2. I have a jsp that has several JSP included. This included JSPs all have the `<nested:root>` tag on it.

I have found little to nothing on this particular tag except that is similar to `<html:root>`, so I've added the `include` statement in my main JSP and I added the `<html:form>` to the sub JSPs but it didn't work.

I had initially just added `<s:form>` to the sub JSPs and the code in the sub JSP was passed along but none of the tags existing in the sub JSP were processed.

Answer (score 1):

All `nested` tags and all Struts1 tags should be removed/replaced with equivalent Struts2 tags.

Nested tags not needed in Struts2 because it's powered with OGNL. Using OGNL expressions and [`<s:include>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/include-tag.html) allows to replace nested tags.

If it's not enough to render content with `s:include` you can use [`<s:action>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/action-tag.html) but it's heavy and it recreates a `valueStack` when this tag executes, so it's rarely used, but custom tags or custom components that include Fremarker or Velocity templates can significantly change the rendering time and allows customization.