# Migrating struts 1 nested tag to struts 2

Tags: hashmap, nested, struts2, iteration

I am migrating struts 1 application to struts 2. I am unable to migrate struts 1 nested tag to struts 2. Could you please help.

I saw some answers to use the s:push tag but unable to use in my scenario.

How to rewrite below logic in struts 2. (Nested Tag)

I found there is no tag in struts 2 that works like nested tag in struts 1.

```
<nested:define property="overridesMap" id="overridesMap" />
                    <%
                        Set ovrSet = ((Map)overridesMap).keySet();
                        Iterator ovrIterator = ovrSet.iterator();   
                        int vfCounter = 0;                          
                     %>
                    <%  while (ovrIterator.hasNext())
                        {
                            //String cssClass = "";
                            String ovrKey = (String)ovrIterator.next();
                            String ovrFieldValue = "field("+ovrKey+")";
                            OverrideDisplay display = (OverrideDisplay)((Map)overridesMap).get(ovrKey);

                            //Create the tag for the vf combination date.
                            StringBuffer vfBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                            vfBuffer.append("VF(");
                            vfBuffer.append(display.getVendorFacility().getHashString());
                            vfBuffer.append(")");
                            String vfId = vfBuffer.toString();

                            String displayUpdateId = vfId + ".updated";
                            String displayAddNewRowId = vfId + ".addNewRow";
                            int effCount = 1;
                            int viewableRowCount = 0;                           
                    %>
                    <table class="displayTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="">
                            <nested:nest property="<%=ovrFieldValue%>">
                                <%      
                                    Map effMap = (Map)display.getEffectiveDateMap();        
                                    Set effSet = effMap.keySet();
                                    Iterator effIter = effSet.iterator();
                                    int effMapSize = effMap.size();
                                %>
                                <%  while (effIter.hasNext())
                                    {
                                        String effKey = (String)effIter.next();
                                        String effFieldValue="field("+effKey+")";
                                        EffectiveDate effectiveDate = (EffectiveDate)effMap.get(effKey);

                                        //Create the tag for the effective date.
                                        StringBuffer effBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                                        effBuffer.append(vfId);
                                        effBuffer.append(".EF(");
                                        effBuffer.append(effCount);
                                        effBuffer.append(")");
                                        String effectiveDateId = effBuffer.toString();
                                        String effectiveDateSelectId = effectiveDateId + ".selected";
                                        String effectiveDateUpdatedId = effectiveDateId + ".updated";
                                        String effectiveDateUpdatedTypeId = effectiveDateId + ".updateType";
                                        String hiddenRowClass = ( (effectiveDate.getUpdateType() == EffectiveDate.DELETE) ||
                                                                  (effectiveDate.isIntersect()) ||
                                                                  (effectiveDate.isHideRow()) ) ? "hideRow" : "";
                                        if(hiddenRowClass.equals("")){
                                            viewableRowCount++;
                                        }
                                %>                                      
                                        <nested:nest property="<%=effFieldValue%>">
                                        <tr class="<%=hiddenRowClass %>">
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn rowSelectorCol">
                                                <nested:checkbox property="selected" 
                                                                 styleId="selected"
                                                                 onclick=""
                                                                 title="<%=effectiveDateSelectId%>"/>
                                                <nested:hidden property="rowNumber" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="intersect" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="hideRow" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="hasValidVF" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="hasErrors" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="updated" 
                                                               styleId="<%=effectiveDateUpdatedId%>" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="updateType" 
                                                               styleId="<%=effectiveDateUpdatedTypeId%>" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn errorCol">
                                                <nested:equal property="hasErrors" value="true">
                                                <nested:hidden property="errorDescription"/>
                                                <nested:define property="errorDescription" id="errDesc" />
                                                    <span class="redX" title="<%=errDesc %>">X</span>
                                                </nested:equal>
                                                <nested:notEqual property="hasErrors" value="true">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </nested:notEqual>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn vendorCol">
                                                <%if( (viewableRowCount == 1) && (hiddenRowClass.equals("")) ){%>
                                                <nested:write property="../vendorFacility.masterVendor.vendorNumber" />
                                                <%}%>
                                                <%if(effCount == 1){ %>
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.vendor.vendorNumber" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.vendor.vendorDeptNumber" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.masterVendor.vendorNumber" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.masterVendor.vendorDeptNumber" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.isValid" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../updated" styleId="<%=displayUpdateId%>"/>
                                                <nested:hidden property="../addNewRow" styleId="<%=displayAddNewRowId%>"/>
                                                <%}else{%>
                                                 &nbsp;
                                                <%} %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn vendorNameCol">
                                                <%if( (viewableRowCount == 1) && (hiddenRowClass.equals("")) ){%>
                                                <nested:write property="../vendorFacility.masterVendor.vendorName" />
                                                <%}%>
                                                <%if(effCount == 1){ %>
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.vendor.vendorName" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.masterVendor.vendorName" />
                                                <%}else{%>
                                                 &nbsp;
                                                <%} %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn facilityCol">
                                                <%if( (viewableRowCount == 1) && (hiddenRowClass.equals("")) ){%>
                                                <nested:write property="../vendorFacility.facility.facilityNumber" />
                                                <%}%>
                                                <%if(effCount == 1){ %>
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.facility.facilityNumber" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.facility.facilityBUID" />
                                                <%}else{%>
                                                 &nbsp;
                                                <%} %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn facilityNameCol">
                                                <%if( (viewableRowCount == 1) && (hiddenRowClass.equals("")) ){%>
                                                <nested:write property="../vendorFacility.facility.facilityName" />
                                                <%}%>
                                                <%if(effCount == 1){ %>
                                                <nested:hidden property="../vendorFacility.facility.facilityName" />
                                                <%}else{%>
                                                 &nbsp;
                                                <%} %>
                                            </td>

                                            <%      
                                                Map ovrRecMap = (Map)effectiveDate.getOverrideRecordMap();      
                                                Set ovrRecSet = ovrRecMap.keySet();
                                                Iterator ovrRecIter = ovrRecSet.iterator();
                                            %>
                                            <%  while (ovrRecIter.hasNext())
                                                {
                                                    String ovrRecKey = (String)ovrRecIter.next();
                                                    String ovrRecFieldValue="field("+ovrRecKey+")";
                                                    OverrideRecord overrideRecord = (OverrideRecord)ovrRecMap.get(ovrRecKey);
                                                    String systemDay = "";
                                                    if(overrideRecord.isSystemDay())
                                                    {
                                                        systemDay = "systemDay";
                                                    }
                                                    //Create the tag for the override record.
                                                    StringBuffer ovrBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                                                    ovrBuffer.append(effectiveDateId);
                                                    ovrBuffer.append(".OVR(");
                                                    ovrBuffer.append(overrideRecord.getDayOfWeek());
                                                    ovrBuffer.append(")");

                                                    String ovrId = ovrBuffer.toString();
                                                    String ovrUpdated = ovrId + ".updated";
                                                    String ovrUpdateType = ovrId + ".updateType";
                                                    String ovrType = ovrId + ".overrideType";
                                                    String overrideId = ovrId + ".overrideId";
                                            %>
                                                <nested:nest property="<%=ovrRecFieldValue%>">      
                                                    <nested:equal property="../active" value="true">                                            
                                                    <td class="rowData multiColumn overrideCol <%=systemDay%>">
                                                        <nested:write property="overrideTypeDesc"/>
                                                        <nested:hidden property="overrideTypeDesc"/>
                                                        <nested:hidden property="dayOfWeek" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="systemDay" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="updated" 
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrUpdated%>"/>
                                                        <nested:hidden property="overrideType"
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrType%>" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="updateType"
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrUpdateType%>" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="overrideId"
                                                                       styleId="<%=overrideId%>" />
                                                    </td>   
                                                    </nested:equal>
                                                    <nested:notEqual property="../active" value="true">

                                                    <td class="rowData multiColumn overrideCol <%=systemDay%>">
                                                        <nested:equal property="systemDay" value="true">
                                                        <nested:select property="overrideType"
                                                                       styleClass="selectBox"
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrType%>"
                                                                       onchange="javascript: registerChange('ovr', this);">
                                                            <html:option value="0">&nbsp;</html:option>
                                                            <html:option value="2">S</html:option>
                                                        </nested:select>
                                                        </nested:equal>
                                                        <nested:notEqual property="systemDay" value="true">
                                                        <nested:select property="overrideType"
                                                                       styleClass="selectBox"
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrType%>"
                                                                       onchange="javascript: registerChange('ovr', this);">
                                                            <html:option value="0">&nbsp;</html:option>
                                                            <html:option value="1">A</html:option>
                                                        </nested:select>
                                                        </nested:notEqual>

                                                        <nested:hidden property="overrideTypeDesc"/>
                                                        <nested:hidden property="dayOfWeek" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="systemDay" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="updated"
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrUpdated%>" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="updateType"
                                                                       styleId="<%=ovrUpdateType%>" />
                                                        <nested:hidden property="overrideId"
                                                                       styleId="<%=overrideId%>" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    </nested:notEqual>
                                                </nested:nest>
                                            <%  } %>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn dateCol">
                                                <nested:equal property="forEmptyVF" value="true">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </nested:equal>
                                                <nested:notEqual property="forEmptyVF" value="true">     
                                                <%
                                                    String startDateId = effectiveDateId + ".start";                                                    
                                                    String startOnClickText = "javascript: openCalendar('" + startDateId + "', false); return false;";
                                                    boolean disabled = (effectiveDate.isActive())? true : false;
                                                 %>                                                                     
                                                <nested:text property="startDateText" 
                                                             styleClass="dateBox" 
                                                             maxlength="10"
                                                             styleId="<%=startDateId%>"
                                                             readonly="<%=disabled%>" 
                                                             onchange="javascript: return registerChange('effDt', this);"/>&nbsp;                                               
                                                <html:image src="images/cal_icon.gif"                                                           
                                                            styleClass="dateImage" 
                                                            onclick="<%=startOnClickText%>"
                                                            disabled="<%=disabled%>"/>
                                                </nested:notEqual>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn dateCol">
                                                <nested:hidden property="active" />
                                                <nested:hidden property="forEmptyVF" />
                                                <nested:equal property="forEmptyVF" value="true">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </nested:equal>

                                                <nested:notEqual property="forEmptyVF" value="true">
                                                <%
                                                    String endDateId = effectiveDateId + ".end"; 
                                                    String endOnClickText = "javascript: openCalendar('" + endDateId + "', false, true); return false;";
                                                %>
                                                <nested:text property="endDateText" 
                                                             styleClass="dateBox" 
                                                             maxlength="10"
                                                             styleId="<%=endDateId%>"
                                                             onchange="javascript: return registerChange('effDt', this);"/>&nbsp;                                               
                                                <html:image src="images/cal_icon.gif"                                                           
                                                            styleClass="dateImage" 
                                                            onclick="<%=endOnClickText%>"/>
                                                </nested:notEqual>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="rowData multiColumn endRow actionCol">
                                                <nested:equal property="hasAddButton" value="true">
                                                <%
                                                    String addOnClick = "javascript: submitForm('add'," +
                                                        "'vf=" + display.getVendorFacility().getHashString() + "');"    ;
                                                %>
                                                <span style="width: 40px;">
                                                    <html:button property="add" 
                                                                 value="Add" 
                                                                 styleClass="addButton" 
                                                                 onclick="<%=addOnClick%>"/>
                                                </span>
                                                <nested:hidden property="hasAddButton" />
                                                </nested:equal>
                                                <nested:notEqual property="hasAddButton" value="true">
                                                <span style="width: 40px;">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </span> 
                                                </nested:notEqual>                                      
                                                <nested:equal property="active" value="false">
                                                <%
                                                    String deleteOnClick = "javascript: submitForm('delete'," +
                                                        "'vf=" + display.getVendorFacility().getHashString() + "&" +
                                                        "effDt=" + effectiveDate.getHashString()+ "');";
                                                 %>
                                                <span style="width: 40px;">
                                                    <html:button property="delete" 
                                                                 value="Delete" 
                                                                 styleClass="delButton"
                                                                 onclick="<%=deleteOnClick%>" />
                                                </span>
                                                </nested:equal>
                                                <nested:equal property="active" value="true">
                                                <span style="width: 40px;">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </span>
                                                </nested:equal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>                                               
                                        </nested:nest>  

                                <%      effCount++;
                                    } %>
                            </table>
                            <br/>
                            </nested:nest>
                    <%      vfCounter++;
                        } %>
```

Comment: Why are you "unable to use" `<s:push>`? The code, by the way, is almost complete opaque: this is a ridiculous chunk of JSP. There are so many ways it's wrong it's difficult to know where to begin, and it's 300+ lines of cruft that trying to understand why you "can't" use `<s:push>` is essentially impossible without any context. There's duplicated logic, scriptlets that even back *then* aren't necessary, poor formatting decisions that make reading this even *more* difficult, and data manipulation that belongs anywhere else but the view.

Comment: There is essentially no reasonable way to expect that someone with zero knowledge of what's going on in this abomination to help in any meaningful way. On the positive side, there's so much room for improvement and cleanup that you'll end up with something people can actually work with.

Comment: I don't see anything here (in as much as anybody can understand any of this) that isn't trivially solved by `<s:iterator>` and normal S2 tags, although I'd invest some time in some custom tags (likely JSP-based) and a bunch of utility functions.

Comment: A less-suckily-formatted version of this file with a few trivial cleanups is here: https://github.com/davelnewton/code-notes/blob/master/stackOverflow/57153931/formatted.jsp. I removed the indecision about `StringBuffer` vs. concatenation, removed some unused variables, and flattened out most of the lines in an attempt to help people understand what's going on in the code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890478/573032